# Different Position of an Element in the XIB and the Simulator / iOS Devices

Tags: objective-c, xib

I implemented a small mapView (65x65) in a scrollView in a viewController. If i set the Position of the mapView per XIB and run it on the Simulator or iOS Devices it is not sitting on the right Position:

- XIB right position
- iPhone 5 to high
- iPhone 4 (or Simulator) much to high

I can correct the position for each situation with these codes, but this cant be the solution:

Code for the same Position in the XIP:

```
CGRect newFrameMapView = CGRectMake(10,171,65,65);
mapView.frame = newFrameMapView;
```

Code to correct it for the output on iPhone 5:

```
CGRect newFrameMapView = CGRectMake(10,215,65,65);
mapView.frame = newFrameMapView;
```

Code to correct it for the output on iPhone 4:

```
CGRect newFrameMapView = CGRectMake(10,302,65,65);
mapView.frame = newFrameMapView;
```

Notes:

- I have got a navigationController on the top.
- Nothing changes if i put the mapView out of the scrollView.
- I dont use Autolayout

--- Edit --- 23.01.2013 -----------------------------------

I 've renamed the "mapView" into "mapView2" to make sure not to change the position on other parts of my code.

Here are the important code fragments of the .h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerDetail : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView2;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView2;

@end
```

and the .m

```
@implementation ViewControllerDetail

@synthesize mapView2;
```

[...]

```
// Basic Settings Map

[mapView2 setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView2 setZoomEnabled:NO];
[mapView2 setScrollEnabled:NO];
[mapView2 setDelegate:self];

// Map Start

MKCoordinateRegion myStartRegion = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0} };
myStartRegion.center.latitude = 44.087439;
myStartRegion.center.longitude = 2.139614;
myStartRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.003;
myStartRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.003;
[mapView2 setRegion:myStartRegion animated:NO];


// Map Point

MKCoordinateRegion myBeispielRegion = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0} };
myRegion1.center.latitude = 44.087439;
myRegion1.center.longitude = 2.139614;
classAnnotation *annotationRegion1 = [[classAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationRegion1.coordinate = myRegion1.center;
[mapView2 addAnnotation:annotationRegion1];
```

Comment: I add some fragments of my code. I hope it clarifies my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the mistake:

(Dunno if this is normal, i use Xcode Version 4.5)

If i insert an MapView in the Xib it is automatically set on Autosizing left/bottom. I didn't noticed that, i thought the standard autosizing is left/top.